# Whose drugs are actually being kept in the storehouse?

Tags: black-butler

In episode 2, entitled 'His Butler, Strongest', whose drugs are being kept in the storehouse? Are they actually Azzurro's drugs, or are they someone else's and he just wants to get his hands on them to sell them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be drugs that do belong to Lau's operation to handle within England. But since they are being stolen and trafficked it was Ciel's job to track down and eliminate them.